# Primary key increment column not pulling through to Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a SQL table I created in Visual Studio with the following settings:

[image]

[image]

However when it comes to my windows form, when i click add new it isn't auto adding the `1000` to the `EmployeeID` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity specification works on data layer (e.g. SQL Server database), so you will receive values starting from 1000 only after inserting the data.

So, unless "add new" is not actually inserting the record and reloading it (at least get the `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY` to populate `EmployeeID` property) I expect to have `EmployeeID = 0`.

Comment: Ok when i try to insert data from the form i leave the `employeeID` blank but get the error `employeeID does not allow nulls` so its not adding the increment?

Comment: It is not clear how do you actually try to insert the data. You specified the table definition and the fact that you are using a form, but I have not idea what that form contains in order for the data to reach the database. Without, it is really hard to answer.